# Maven - merge auto and manual list of imported packages

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans, osgi

I work in netbeans 7.4 and use maven for building my projects. Earlier I didn't write any packages to import in pom file as it was done automatically.

Now I need to add some package manually. For this I use maven-bundle-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
       <instructions>
          <Import-Package>org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib</Import-Package>
       </instructions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>bundle-manifest</id>
           <phase>process-classes</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>manifest</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
         <execution>
           <id>bundle-install</id>
           <phase>install</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>install</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that this case all packages that were imported automatically are not imported now. How can I merge manual and auto list of imported packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default for `Import-Package` in bnd/maven-bundle-plugin is '*', which means "import all packages which the bundle needs".

You have overridden this default to import the package `org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib` *and only* that package.

Whenever you add packages manually, you must always specify a trailing '*' to include all the other packages that the code might depend on. So:

```
<Import-Package> org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib, * </Import-Package>
```

This means roughly as follows: "import `org.apache.tiles.jps.taglib` plus any other packages that the bundle needs".

Answer (score 2):

What about this one?

```
<Import-Package>
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib,
    *
</Import-Package>
```